# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Printing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor WebAssmbly 3.1 application. I can not get the printer list. I have tried below code snippets. Its occur error.

```
@using System.Drawing;
@code {
 public List<string> PrinterCollection = new List<string>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()

    {
        foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            PrinterCollection.Add(printer);
        }
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not on Windows anymore. Forget about using System.Drawing. Look up Blazor and Printing,

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I am using windows. The serverside application working fine. The issue occurs only clientside application

Comment: Your client should be able to run on Linux/iOS/... . That is why we have Web Apps.

Comment: And, your server-side app will show you the list of printers _on the server_.

Comment: My guess is that your run into a limitation of WASM. Like with other library parts (sockets for instance), you can't use them in WASM. I guess there is no way for Web Assembly to gain access to the printer. So you have to find a way. I guess JS interop will lead you there.